Is electron spin "direction" from beta decay same (left-right symmetry related)?
From "Richard P. Feynman - The Character of Physical Law" (First published by the British Broadcasting Corporation 1965):

Lee and Yang* proposed that maybe the principle of right and left
symmetry – that nature is the same for right and left – is not
correct, and that this would help to explain a number of mysteries.
Lee and Yang proposed some more direct experiments to demonstrate
this, and I will just mention the most direct of all the experiments
done.
... a radioactive disintegration in which, for instance, an electron and a
neutrino are emitted – an example, which we have talked about before,
is the disintegration of a neutron into a proton, an electron and an
anti-neutrino ...  if you measure the spin – electrons are spinning as
they come out – you find out that they are spinning to the left (as
seen from behind – i.e. if they are going south, they turn in the same
direction as does the earth).
* Tsung-Dao Lee and Chen Ning Yang, Chinese physicists, joint Nobel
Prize 1957.

I could not find such info by googling and reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay. Maybe the statement from the book was later found to be incorrect? Or is it deemed of small significance? Or could it be the book's "done" is to be read "to be done" - only proposed?

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_experiment

Nobody gets a Nobel prize for experiments that aren't yet done.

@PM2Ring The Wu experiment didn't measure electron spin, just nuclear spin. See my answer.

I'm not sure which of two things you're asking, so I'll answer both with several references.
The Wu et al. experiment in 1957 measured the correlation between a nuclear spin and the direction of the emitted electron's momentum.  The Wu experiment was not sensitive to the electron spin.
Lederman and collaborators threw together a pion decay experiment when they heard about Wu's result in press; their result was published in Physical Review on the page after the Wu paper. They showed that pions, which can't be polarized because they don't have spin, emit strongly polarized muons when they beta decay.
The spin polarization of beta decay electrons was actually discovered thirty years earlier by Cox and collaborators (1927).  Cox wanted a source of unpolarized electrons to measure Mott scattering, and switched to a thermal electron source after publishing.  The significance of the parity violation was missed, and the Cox experiment was forgotten until Grodzins uncovered it in a 1958 literature review.
The polarization of the neutrino was first measured by Goldhaber and collaborators at the end of 1957.
A nice history is Allan Franklin's book "Are there really neutrinos?"
(Apologies if I have flubbed anybody's name or date.)

I want to know two things: 1) does electron goes from beta-decay always same-threaded as described in the book? 2) does (1) means left-right symmetry is broken? --- So... does your answer "The spin polarization of beta decay" means (1)? Does 1 leads to 2 of could be another explanation? -- I guess yes to both 1) https://www.researchgate.net/publication/347120344_Once_Came_Close_to_Being_Enough_Electron_Polarization_and_Parity_Nonconservation 2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics) proper words are "the weak interaction is chiral", correct?

Yes to both.  In modern language, the charged-current weak interaction only involves left-chiral electrons; right-chiral electrons are invisible to the flavor-changing weak interaction.  In the relativistic limit, a left-chiral electron has completely left-handed helicity, which is the spin polarization we can measure in an experiment. But in its rest frame, an electron is equal parts left-chiral and right-chiral. So the spin polarization of beta-decay electrons gets stronger and stronger as the energies of the decays increase. Mirror symmetry, which reverses helicity, is broken.
